# Office Online vs Office 365 for SharePoint 2019 On-Premise

Tags: office, sharepoint-server

We're currently planning our migration from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2019. In our current 2013 environment, we have a dedicated server running Office Web Apps to handle the rendering of Office documents such as Word, Excel, etc. For 2019, do we have to provision a similar server for Office Online Server, or can we leverage our existing subscription to Office 365 to handle document rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You must deploy Office Online Server if you want browser-based editing -- there is no hybrid functionality for Office Online in M365.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but can you please elaborate on what you mean by 'there is no hybrid functionality for Office Online in O365' ?

Comment: What you're asking is for hybrid functionality with Office Online. That doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to host our documents in the SharePoint 2019, then we need to configure the office online server.

**Now the question is, can we use the same office online server what we were using in SharePoint 2013?**

Yes, we can use but we must enhance the server configuration, the server should fulfill the below prerequisites:

**Supported operating systems:**

You can run Office Online Server on the following operating systems:

- The 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2012 R2
- The 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2016 (Office Online Server April 2017 or later required).

**Firewall requirements**

Make sure the following ports aren’t blocked by firewalls on either the server that runs Office Online Server or the load balancer:

- Port 443 for HTTPS traffic
- Port 80 for HTTP traffic
- Port 809 for private traffic between the servers that run Office Online Server (if you’re setting up a multi-server farm)

**DNS requirements**

In environments that use HTTPS and load balancing, you have to update DNS so that the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the certificate resolves to either the IP address of the server that runs Office Online Server or to the IP address assigned to the load balancer for the Office Online Server farm.

Reference :

[Deploy Office Online Server for SharePoint 2019](https://spmonkey.com/sharepoint/deploy-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-2019/)

**Can we skip the office online server in SharePoint 2019?**

Yes, but we must purchase the tenant subscription in the office 365 and the document should be hosted in SharePoint online. Then we do not need server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. Can you provide details how this can be achieved: